# Access Denied - After Typing Firebase Init?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I just registered my own domain on GCP and instead, created a new GCP. I wanted to migrate my old GCP to new one. So, I signed in using `firebase login:ci`. The new window opened up to choose my account and I used my new assigned account for registered domain on new GCP. Then I run firebase init inside. I got this error after selecting firebase project I created using a new GCP.

> Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied to get service [firestore.googleapis.com]
> Help Token: AWzfkCMe3kI1xtpLJkoCpzQg-sn3fQt7oX8VPut5qpv5cBZcYLNuMwx9Ml1UofnrC9fStBNhbTPnPBJlx-jiM4Br3U-pBp91mmYWnqnrOxClIEQY

Comment: If you are just try to authenticate yourself then try `firebase login`. `firebase login:ci` is used for authentication in CI pipelines.

Comment: Correct. I just tried this and it worked. I just logout and login as usual and now no more errors. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`firebase login:ci`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems) command is used for authentication in CI pipelines. To authenticate yourself to for Firebase CLI, use [`firebase login`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#sign-in-test-cli).

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Dharmaraj you can use `firebase login` to Log into Firebase using your Google account. This command connects your local machine to Firebase and grants you access to your Firebase projects.